# Efficient Calculation of Determinant on change for 3X3 matrix?

Tags: c++, c, math, matrix, language-agnostic

Let's say you were given a 3x3 matrix of values and only a particular column changes values between iterations.

On Step 1 I have X:

```
[2.0, 4.6, 3.4]
[3.2, 6.7, 4.1]
[2.1, 1.4, 5.3]
```

Whose determinant is -11.476

Now on Step 2 I have X, with the second column populated with new values.

```
[2.0, 6.5, 3.4]
[3.2, 3.4, 4.1]
[2.1, 0.8, 5.3]
```

Is there a quick way to calculate the determinant of this matrix given the previous state of the matrix and its previous determinant? I want to preserve some of the information known at the previous state. Only columns change on each iteration.

Comment: Note that if you're using floating point and the results are inexact, there's a good chance that you will accumulate error, possibly very large error over time, by using such a method. If it matters you need to do some analysis on whether/how error might accumulate and determine if it affects your usage, and if so, how you might compensate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's always the same column that changes you can use [Laplace expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) with respect to that column.

Answer (score 2):

If your first and third columns are constant and only second column varies, then you can transform this into a formula:

[2.0, a, 3.4]
[3.2, b, 4.1]
[2.1, c, 5.3]
= -a x [3.2, 4.1][2.1, 5.3] + b x [2.0, 3.4][2.1, 5.3] - c x [2.0, 3.4][3.2, 4.1]
= **-8.35 x a + 3.46 x b + 2.68 x c**

So now you have a formula that you can use.